# Write down a parity-check matrix for the Hamming code Ham$(3, 3)$ and use it to decode the vector $0111111111111$

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

The solution I have been given is the following

$$H = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&1&1&2&2&2\\1&0&1&2&0&1&2&0&1&2&0&1&2\end{pmatrix}$$

The syndrome $S(011111111111111111) = 1(100)$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$. Thus we decode y as the codeword
$111101111111111111$

I understand how to decode y but struggling to understand where the entries to the parity-check matrix come from?

Comment: Look at the columns of $H$. They are all the vectors with the property that the first non-zero entry is equal to one. That is the usual normalization trick designed to guarantee that A) the columns are pairwise linearly independent (implying minimum distance three) and B) as all thirteen such vectors are present, we also get a covering code (any vector is at Hamming distance $\le1$ from a codeword.

Comment: Assuming the received word is the one with 13 symbols (in the title) as opposed to the one with $18$ (in the question body) it looks like you miscalculated the syndrome. It looks like a single $0$ followed by twelve $1$s is a codeword. I got a syndrome of all zeros.

Comment: I mean, the inner products of that vector and the rows of $H$ are $9,12,12$. All $\equiv0\pmod 3$.